# React how can you pass a variable to a get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to query from a table where the `teacherId` is equal to the `teacherId` of the person that logs in but I can't pass that `teacherId` from the front-end to the back-end.

This is the back end

```
app.get("/api/get", async(req,res) => {
    const teacherId = req.body.teacherId
    connection.query(
        "SELECT class FROM homework WHERE teacherID = ?",
        [teacherId],
        (err, result) => {
            if (result){
                res.send({ message: result })
            } else{
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

This is the front end

```
 useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/get", {
            teacherId: teacherId
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response){
                setDisplayHomework(response.data.message)
            } else{
                console.log("error")
            }
        })
    })
```

```
const teacherId = localStorage.getItem("teacherId")
```

I think the problem lies where it says `teacherId: teacherId` but I don't know why.

Comment: Do you want to send a `param` in the url?

Comment: @Alessandro No I want to pass the variable teacherId from the front end to the back end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/get", {
     params: { teacherId }
 });
```

and use `req.query.teacherId` to read it

---

If you see the [`Axios.get`](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) signature it is

> axios.get(url[, config])

in contrast to

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

which passes the data as the second argument.

That is because the body in `GET` requests is not used by the servers. Read [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not send a body with a get request. Put the teacher id into the url. Then this is called path variable.

```
app.use('/teacher/:teacherId', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.teacherId);
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Get requests don't have request bodies unlike post requests, as such the Axios.get function shouldn't have a second parameter for the body. Instead pass your parameters as a url, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/get?teacherId="+teacherId).then((response) => {
            if(response){
                setDisplayHomework(response.data.message)
            } else{
                console.log("error")
            }
        })
    })
```

Then in your backend code use req.params to access the get request url parameters:

```
app.get("/api/get", async(req,res) => {
    const teacherId = req.params.teacherId
    connection.query(
        "SELECT class FROM homework WHERE teacherID = ?",
        [teacherId],
        (err, result) => {
            if (result){
                res.send({ message: result })
            } else{
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
```